# Why is there no Owner in the list of iam-admin/roles

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

In the list of Roles, why is there no "Owner" role?

[image]

**Update**: I found that I can filter and get owner if I filter: roles/owner. And the role Owner is actually in the list after submitting.
Problem solved, but still strange with the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: The **links** you have provided are **not publicly accessible** as they lead to your project.

Since you mentioned that you can see the 'Owner' role on the page with your project's permissions, it should also be listed on the [Roles](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles?project=) page in Cloud Console.

Did you try to search for it using the 'Filter'?

Comment: Thanks sfo rinfo, and yes I used the filter

Comment: Found that if I filter with "roles/owner" it shows... hmm

Comment: And it does not show filtering with "Owner" or "owner", then it shows all other like "BigQuery owner"

Comment: Glad to hear that you found it. For me searching just for "owner" in the filter worked well; of course, it gives all the roles that include that word but it's much easier to find it already.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that, I am on Safari.. Will just try in Chrom :-)

Comment: Nope, same thing in Chrome

Comment: You're on the 'Roles' page in the Cloud Console and are searching for the 'Owner' role using the filter ("Filter table"), right?

Comment: Yes, correct - I will add an image

Comment: Please make sure to remove/hide any sensitive information

Comment: Thanks, just did :-)

Comment: Submit it after entering "owner" (or "roles/owner") and you should get the result.

Comment: Please confirm if you could see it after submitting.

Comment: Hey, yes - what the, I was sure, etc. :-)  I must have been to focused on the dropdown box, showing. I can now confirm that it does show in the list after submitting. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, Chris! Glad we could clarify it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize - a **filter** can be used to find the required role on the [**Roles**](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles?project=) page in Cloud Console.

Simply, go to the "Filter table" field and submit the role you are looking for.

In this particular situation, you can find the 'Owner' role by searching for "owner" *(which will give you a list of the roles that include this word)* or, alternatively, "roles/owner".